# mariadb going to 100% CPU usage even with query_cache_size = 0

Tags: mariadb

I have configured mariadb with following config:

```
query_cache_size = 0
query_cache_type = 0
```

But still mariadb hangs after a while with CPU 100%. I checked processlist and I get 'Waiting for query cache lock`' for 20+ processes inside mysql cli. All of them waiting for more than thousands of seconds. I have seen this so many times now. (To add to this, we are a shared hosting provider with many users accessing the database at the same time).

I also notice that there is always one process with

```
Query   | 6301 | closing tables               | DROP DATABASE `vafagimone5854_V2JewLtWqhsB7inA1cO3`
```

Is this a clue?

Also, when I ran `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'have_query_cache';` :

```
+------------------+-------+
| Variable_name    | Value |
+------------------+-------+
| have_query_cache | YES   |
+------------------+-------+
```

and `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'query_cache_size';`:

```
+------------------+----------+
| Variable_name    | Value    |
+------------------+----------+
| query_cache_size | 16777216 |
+------------------+----------+
```

This is super weird as I have the cache disabled. Eventually, I killed `mariadbd` and restarted the server process, which is obviously not ideal.

But to my surprise the variables are ok now:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'query_cache_size';
+------------------+-------+
| Variable_name    | Value |
+------------------+-------+
| query_cache_size | 0     |
+------------------+-------+
```

However this still shows cache is enabled

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'have_query_cache';
+------------------+-------+
| Variable_name    | Value |
+------------------+-------+
| have_query_cache | YES   |
+------------------+-------+
```

I am super confused, is it possible someone is `query_cache_size` in runtime? and why is `have_query_cache` always 'YES'.

Comment: Which MariaDB version? If you see it again [grap a backtrace snapshot](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/how-to-produce-a-full-stack-trace-for-mysqld/#getting-full-backtraces-for-all-threads-from-a-running-mariadbd-process) and [report a bug](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/how-to-produce-a-full-stack-trace-for-mysqld/#reporting-the-problem).

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[have_query_cache](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#have_query_cache) is a compile time enabled and can't be changed. See also the [query cache kb page](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/query-cache/).

It looks like you changed your configuration file to have `query_cache_size=0` but then it wasn't until you just restarted it that it had an effect. Now that its restarted hopefully the performance is better.

A long time "closing tables" on dropping a database is odd unless there is a very large number of table and a table cache shortage (which is worth checking).

Comment: I think this is what it is. We changed the values sometime back and did `server mariadb reload` - I believe that won't take the changes right?